# Setting priority/niceness within a jupyter/ipython notebook

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to set the CPU priority of a jupyter notebook lower within the notebook? E.g. when running a days long parameter search on a compute server, setting priority within that notebook behind notebooks that others are working on in real-time.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe setting the priority of your `python` process would be enough for you? As possible startet processes inherit the priority.
If yes, the following code my help:

```
import psutil
psutil.Process().nice(19)# if on *ux
psutil.Process().nice(psutil.IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS)# if on win
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can renice the whole server (not aware of any way to renice a particular notebook). If the other notebooks are running on distinct notebook server process, you can do it from a subshell:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
  !for pid in `pgrep -f jupyter`; do { renice -20 $pid; }; done
---------------------------------------------------------------

9721 (process ID) old priority 19, new priority -20
12449 (process ID) old priority 19, new priority -20
25502 (process ID) old priority 19, new priority -20
```

Or, if you want to do it in Python, first get the list of running servers:

```
>>> from notebook import notebookapp
>>> servers = list(notebookapp.list_running_servers())
>>> servers
[{'url': 'http://localhost:8888/', 
  'base_url': '/', 
  'token': '5ea29b3...7e1fba5331ae', 
  'secure': False, 
  'pid': 9721, 
  'hostname': 'localhost', 
  'password': False, 
  'port': 8888, 
  'notebook_dir': '/home/paulos/work'
}]
```

Filter the list for the ones you want if needed.

```
pids = [_['pid'] for _ in servers if meets_condition(_)]
```

Then call setpriority:

```
>>> from ctypes import cdll
>>> libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
>>> pids = [_['pid'] for _ in servers]
>>> for pid in pids:
        print("old priority for PID", pid, "is", libc.getpriority(0, pid))
        libc.setpriority(0, pid, 20)
        print("new priority for PID", pid, "is", libc.getpriority(0, pid))

old priority for PID 9721 is 0
new priority for PID 9721 is 19
```

Comment: renice seems to require sudo. Do you have any suggestions for working around that?

Comment: Interesting, I was under the impression that you should be able to increase the "niceness" of your own processes but if your OS does not allow it you have no alternative but use privilege escalation. You can try to whitelist the renice commando for this user (for not requiring a password in sudo) and use a subshell with the `sh` module, something like `sh.sudo("renice", niceness, pid)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just going to stick with the in-python option as that seems to be working just fine.